# Disclosure Group pushes/widens views below and above it as well widens its own tab/bar

Tags: swiftui, disclosuregroup

I am using two different disclosure groups in a VStack. Whenever I activate the Disclosure Group, it appears to not only widen its own tab/bar (the title part) but any views below the disclosure group also seems to be widened as well.

Before

[image]

After

[image]

Code, the two dropdown sections are placed in a normal vstack, placed in a scroll view

```
var scroll: some view {
```

ScrollView{
scrollStack
}
}

```
    var scrollStack: some View {
    VStack {
        soundAndDSPSection
        subwooferCutoffDropDown
        fullRangeCutoffDropDown
        middleTextView
        slidersView
        learnMoreAdjustmentBurron
        syncButtons
        learnMoreSyncButton
    }
}


var subwooferCutoffDropDown: some View {
    DisclosureGroup("Subwoofer Cutoff (Maximum)") {
        lowpassCrossoverSection
    }
    .padding()
    .accentColor(.trulliBlack)
}

var fullRangeCutoffDropDown: some View {
    DisclosureGroup("Full-Range Cutoff (Minimum)") {
        highpassCrossoverSection
    }.padding()
    .accentColor(.trulliBlack)
}

var lowpassCrossoverSection: some View {
    VStack {
        lowSlopeNumber
        lowSlopeSlider
    }
}

var highpassCrossoverSection: some View {
    VStack {
        highSlopeNumber
        highSlopeSlider
    }
}



var lowSlopeNumber: some View {
    HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
        Text("\(hzLevel.roundToInt()*10+50)")
            .font(.semibold44PN())
        Text("Hz")
        
    }
    .padding(.top)

}

var lowSlopeSlider: some View {
    Slider(value: $hzLevel, in: 0...07) { didChange in
        actions()
    }
    .frame(width: 360)
    .tint(Color.red)
    .padding([.trailing, .leading])
    .padding([.trailing, .leading])
    
}

var highSlopeNumber: some View {
    HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
        Text("\(highHzLevel.roundToInt()*10+80)")
            .font(.semibold44PN())
        Text("Hz")
    }
    .padding(.top)

}

var highSlopeSlider: some View {
    Slider(value: $highHzLevel, in: 0...07) { didChange in
    actions()
    }
    .frame(width: 360)
    .tint(Color.red)
    .padding([.trailing, .leading])
    .padding([.trailing, .leading])
    
}
```